# d3 4.0 - import statement gives __moduleExports wrapper

Tags: typescript, ionic2, rollupjs, es6-modules, d3.js

I'm having trouble with an import statement in D3 4.0 and Ionic2/Angular2 project.

I believe I am using the correct import statement, and everything compiles.

```
import * as d3Request from 'd3-request'; 

export class HomePage { 

  constructor() {

    d3Request.xml('assets/mysvg.svg')
      .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
      .get(function(error, xml) {
        if (error) throw error;
        document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
      });
   }
}
```

Gets compiled to:

```
var d3Request$1 = unwrapExports(d3Request);

var d3Request$2 = Object.freeze({
    default: d3Request$1,
    __moduleExports: d3Request
});

...
 d3Request$2.xml('assets/mysvg.svg')
    .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
    .get(function (error, xml) {
       if (error) throw error;
       document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
    });
```

However, at runtime the `xml` function does not exist on `d3Request$2.xml`. It only exists on `d3Request$2.__moduleExports.xml`, but the code does not compile to that. What gives?

I also tried `import d3Request from 'd3-request'` which also compiles but still doesnt work. Results in:

```
var d3Request$1 = unwrapExports(d3Request);

...
d3Request$1.xml('assets/emojis/laughing.svg')
   .mimeType("image/svg+xml")...
```

However, this still doesn't work because `d3Request$1` end up being undefined. `d3Request.xml` exists but the code doesnt compile to that, it compiles to `d3Request$1.xml`!

Comment: try this: ```import * as d3 from 'd3';  d3.request(...)```

Comment: No, that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unwrapExports(...)` and `__moduleExports` indicate that you're importing a CommonJS file (and transforming it with [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs)), not the ES module version. It's odd that it doesn't work, but no matter – you can bypass the transformation altogether by importing the correct file.

Without seeing your Rollup config file it's impossible to be certain, but I would guess that you're using [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve)? If so, the solution is to ensure that the `jsnext: true` option is set, so that Rollup can find [this file](https://unpkg.com/d3-request@1.0.2/index.js) rather than [this file](https://unpkg.com/d3-request@1.0.2).

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the roll up config that comes build into Ionic2  via ionic-app-scripts. The config exactly is here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/rollup.config.js. Assuming it's being loaded correctly from my node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config, it seems the file is passing `jsnext:true` to  rollup-plugin-node-resolve, as you say.

Comment: That's very odd. I'm not an Ionic user so can't tell if there's something else going on here – another thing you could try is pointing to the file explicitly as e.g. `import * as d3Request from 'd3-request/index.js'`